# Fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional values Unwrapping

Tags: swift, option-type

I have a problem which causes fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional values i must unwrap the cell index in the `print("\(cellindex)")`. I know this code `if let index = cell index {}`but it didn't work, it didn't print anything.

Are there other ways to get this index to unwrap it? 
Thanks for your Help.

```
 var cellindex: NSIndexPath?

 if let index = cellindex {
     print("\(index)")
 }
```

Comment: If your code isn't printing anything, that simply means that `cellindex` is `nil`.

Comment: You're doing it right. Just add an `else` branch for when cellindex is nil, which seems to be the case.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
if cellIndex != nil {
    print(cellIndex)
}
```